# How to get the Selected index and value of a radio button inside an unorderd list using javascript

Tags: javascript, select, radio-button

I have an unordered list that has a radio button. I want to get the ID of the checked radio button.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="class1">
 <li>
  <label id="id1">
   <input id="id1A" type="radio" value="2" name="name1" onchange="say(); return false;">
   <span class="className1">Some Text1</span>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label id="id2">
   <input id="id2A" type="radio" value="1" name="name1" onchange="say(); return false;">
   <span class="className1">Some Text2</span>
  </label>
 </li>
</ul>

<ul class="class2">
 <li>
  <label id="id21">
   <input id="id21A" type="radio" value="2" name="name2" onchange="say(); return false;">
   <span class="className21">Some Text21</span>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label id="id2">
   <input id="id22A" type="radio" value="1" name="name2" onchange="say(); return false;">
   <span class="className21">Some Text22</span>
  </label>
 </li>
</ul>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function say() {
    var firstChild = document.getElementsByClassName('class1');
        firstChild = Array.prototype.slice.call(firstChild);
        for(var j =0; j < parent.length; j++){  
            var firstChildElem = firstChild;
            for (var x = 0; x < secondChild.length; x ++) {
                if (secondChild[x].checked) {
                    alert("You checked " + secondChild[w]);             
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

But this script doesn't work.

Comment: Where are you defining secondChild?

Comment: what do you mean by `selected index`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do this kind of thing. The solution for jQuery would be as simple as this:

```
$("input:radio[name=name1]:checked").val();
```

Where `name1` would be substituded for `name2`. Not sure what you mean with `SelectedIndex` though. Dropdownlists have selectedindexes, but a radiobutton is either checked or not...

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way:
1. Change `onchange="say();` to `onchange="say('CURRID');`

2. New Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function say(currID){
alert("You checked: " + currID);
}
</script>
```

Then, if you don't need the `id="id1A"` parts of the `input` tags anymore, you can delete these parts.

Comment: Your answer does not make sense at all